# How customize initrd via linuxrc

Tags: linux-kernel, initrd

I have the need to use the same disk and so the same bootloader on devices with different motherboard.
Each motherboard has it's own way of mapping devices so sometime the bootdisk is mapped ad hda other as hdc.
I already try to manage this boot with different device assigning

and before start check how thw board mapped the boot device ( hda, hdc , ecc... ) and based on that mapping fix the boot parameter.

I already try to manage the boot from dom with different device replacing the device name with the LABEL option ( grub bootloader ).
But it didn't works

This works

```
title Linux 2.4.37.9
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.4.37.9 ro root=/dev/hda1  console=ttyS0,9600 console=tty0 apm=off
```

This didn't works ( kernel unable to find root=LABEL=Flash-Root )

```
title Linux 2.4.37.9
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.4.37.9 ro root=LABEL=Flash-Root  console=ttyS0,9600 console=tty0 apm=off
```

Some guys suggested my as an alternative solution to manage initrd and so I now trying to manage and fix the boot parameter through the script linuxrc

Mi first question is about documentation about nash, the scripting interpreter used by linuxrc.
I haven't found documentation about how use nash and most important how use nash for linuxrc.
Does someone known how can I find some documentation and samples ?

My second ( and last ) question is about how can I check from insice linuxrc what device ( hda1, hdc1, ecc.. ) is valid and based on that set the right value for the /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev variable.
I think to check the disk using fdisk, but this program require some library to be loaded inside initrd and so I'm looking for a solution which need less space.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be a `/` before your disk label.

Comment: Also, think about using UUIDs. Your issue might also be grub-related: You specify the root device as being `(hd0,0)`, but if you plug the drive into the second SATA port for example, you'd need `(hd1,0)`.

Comment: The disk label was a my error in typing, I have correct it now. But the label didn't works, I mentioned it just to describe better my problem

Comment: could you give us the output of `blkid`?

Comment: I'm using redhat 7.3, there is no blkid available. I use tune2fs BUT my core question was about a tutorial about nash. I have already investigate the use of LABEL and UUID and that is not working.